Converting Smoothed Moving Average from MetaTrader/MetaQuotes to PineScript
I'm trying to write the SMMA(Smoothed Moving Average) that MetaTrader has to PineScript, because they are different. MT5 has the SMMA version that seems to be most popular:https://www.metatrader5.com/en/terminal/help/indicators/trend_indicators/ma#smma
The script i wrote seems to work fine, but it somehow plots a SIMPLE moving average of 800 instead of a Smoothed Moving Average. If i change the 'smma2' and 'smmaFinal' the code breaks(no errors) but nothing gets plotted.
I've written this in Pinescript:
//@version=5
indicator(title="CLASSIC Smoothed Moving Average", shorttitle="CSMMA", overlay=true)
//Inputs
N = input.int(800, minval=1, title="Classic Length")

//Math
sum1 = math.sum(close[0], N)
smma1 = sum1 / N

smma = (smma1 * (N-1) + close[0]) / N 

prevsum = smma[1] * N
smma2 = (prevsum - smma[1] + close[0]) / N

smmaFinal = (smma2[1] * (N-1) + close[0]) / N

//Plots
plot(smmaFinal, color=#89ff29)

The script should display the SMMA as it is in Metatraders 5 default indicators -> Moving Average Smoothed.
